# Kotlin coroutine with no suspend functions

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So I have to make a network call and for that I am using coroutines like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    sendData()
}

private suspend fun sendData() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        withTimeout(5000L) {
           // Sends a network request and handles response using a network function without suspend
        }
    } catch(e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
        ...
    }
}
```

My question is, does this have drawbacks over creating a Runnable? Since there are no suspend functions called from within sendData() and the network function called from this function is a regular blocking call. Is it bad practice to use coroutines here?

Comment: The real drawback is that your network request will be left hanging indefinitely and that's a resource leak in your app.

Comment: Even when using a timeout?

Comment: Nevermind, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a bad practice.

I can see that you are creating a `suspend function` because you want to change thread and specify timeout for the network call.

It is not a must to call `suspend function` inside `another suspend function`.

But, `suspend function` can only be called inside `Coroutine Builder` or `another suspend function`.

Thanks to Marko Topolnik for the details :)

Comment: `CoroutineScope` is just an object, you don't call any suspend functions "from" it. I guess what you had in mind was a coroutine builder like `launch`, which is not itself a suspend fun.

Comment: ah looks like I've used a wrong word for it, it should be "inside". Have edited the answer. Thanks a lot for reminding.

Comment: It didn't make a difference :) The point is that the scope has nothing to do with this story. Coroutine builders are the "magical" non-suspendable functions that execute a block of code which is suspendable. Coroutine scopes didn't even exist in the experimental version of Kotlin Coroutines, their concern is structured concurrency.

Comment: Hmmm, if I don't get it wrong, `suspend function` can only be called inside Coroutine builder not `CoroutineScope`?

Comment: Yes, you can call `launch { suspendFun() }` inside a non-suspendable function.

Comment: Looks like I get what you mean now, thanks a lot for correcting me Marko :)

Comment: I also partly added the timeout because as far as I understand, since the network function is not a suspend function (and runs on the calling thread), the sendData function wont be cancelled, meaning also lifecycleScope is pretty useless here?

Comment: your `lifecycleScope.launch` here acts as a Coroutine Builder. So you are able to call your `suspend function` here. So I would say that it is not useless.

Comment: You are right, I guess only the cancellation part doesn't really work since setData calls a blocking non-suspend function which itself isn't cancellable. Anyway, I ended up using a JobIntentService for this specific case (since I didn't need to update the UI with anything anyway, and I think it is better architecture to decouple it), but I wanted to make sure for later rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTTP request dependency you are using includes a callback, then the library by itself is taking care of threading. Retrofit does that.

So the HTTP request will be none blocking, but the callback will be in the main thread, making unnecessary the suspend.

Similarly, if there is a callback, then a runnable is not needed either.

Please be aware that coroutines and threads are not the same, tend to be related, but not all the coroutines are background thread.

The drawback is what you do after the HTTP request in the callback. Generally, the HTTP request is followed by writing on the DB, so that is why dependencies that provide callbacks, are still wrapped in abstraction and use the blocking method provided.

Comment: The thing is this is a legacy app, and elsewhere in the project AsyncTask is used which uses this custom network class we have, and of course I do not want to keep adding AsycTasks. Retrofit would be better but basically it would be a lot of work to rewrite the network class. Currently this custom network class simply uses HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Then you can keep using `HttpUrlConnection` but wrap that in a coroutine so you can move away from the callback of the `AsyncTask` 

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines#6